# Windows phone 8.0 app certification failure

Tags: windows-phone-8, publishing, windows-store

I had uploaded a windows phone 8.0 app to store around a year ago. Recently, the app has failed their newly updated certification procedure. One of the policies the app supposedly violated is this:-

> 10.1.1 Inaccurate Representation
>
> The app icon displayed on the device doesn’t relate to the icon provided in the metadata.

I couldn't understand why this message is shown. The app's icon is definitely not a copy. What other issues might be causing this failure?

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't understand why this message is shown. The app's icon is
>   definitely not a copy. What other issues might be causing this
>   failure?

According to the failure report, your app icon may not be related with the content of your app so tester failed it for violating Store Policy.

Another possibility is that tester find it similar to another app's icon as a result of check. In case of that you'd better contact [Dev Center support](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that they can review your specific submission.

When you resubmit your app, it's recommended to add additional info you want tester know in [Notes for certification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/notes-for-certification) option. This may help you pass certification better.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will send an email to the windows store team. The app was available on store for over a year. It will be very disappointing if they find the app's icon similar to some other app at this point.

Comment: Please don't e-mail the original address in the answer - they do not do Store support. It is for fraud / abuse / etc.

Comment: Isn't there any authentic email ID for the windows store support team?